# How to authorize and fetch twitter user's timeline via api

Tags: php, twitter

I am a newbie to oAuth and twitter api, what I want to do is fetch user's timeline. I have registered my app and have got my keys. Is there any simple method to authenticate and fetch the data in php? I don't want to use any external libraries and class for now because I want to learn the internal workings too. :)

Here are my basic cURL request code:

```
$url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=user';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$output=curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $output;
```

But how to authenticate???

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest the course of [Ray Villalobos](http://www.lynda.com/Ray-Villalobos/832401-1.html), an author at [lynda.com](http://lynda.com/) - he tells you how to do such a thing [on his website](http://iviewsource.com/codingtutorials/working-with-the-twitter-api-1-1-changes-with-video/). Good luck!